# Regular expression to match a word but not inside backticks

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is an example of different paragraphs

```
Upgrade is the first word in this paragraph.
In this paragraph, upgrade is the last word.
And this paragraph endsupgrade with upgrade.
But I don't want to upgradefind that word in this command `gigalixir:upgrade`.
```

As you can see there are 6 instances of upgrade word in above mentioned four lines. I am trying to find all the upgrade words except the one at the last (because that word is inside the command inside backticks). I also do not want to find upgrade words that are not independent.

So in the above sentence following words marked with double * should be selected:

```
**Upgrade** is the first word in this paragraph.
In this paragraph, **upgrade** is the last word.
And this paragraph endsupgrade with **upgrade**.
But I don't want to upgradefind that word in this command `gigalixir:upgrade`.
```

I have tried this simple regex:

```
/\bupgrade\b/gi
```

That selects all the independent words but I want to ignore the upgrade word inside backticks.

**Note:** I do not want to use lookahead or lookbehind, because I am executing this regex inside browser and any browser except chrome does not support that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match strings inside backticks and skip them and only match a word `upgrade` in all other contexts as a whole word:

```js
const text = 'Upgrade is the first word in this paragraph.\nIn this paragraph, upgrade is the last word.\nAnd this paragraph endsupgrade with upgrade.\nBut I don\'t want to upgradefind that word in this command `gigalixir:upgrade`.';
const regex = /(`[^`]*`)|\bupgrade\b/gi;
console.log(text.replace(regex, (x,y) => y || `**${x}**`));
```

The `` (`[^`]*`)|\bupgrade\b `` regex matches

- `` (`[^`]*`) `` - Capturing group 1 (it will help analyze the match structure later): a backtick, zero or more chars other than a backtick, and a backtick
- `|` - or
- `\bupgrade\b` - a whole word `upgrade` (case insensitively due to `i` flag).

The `` .replace(regex, (x,y) => y || `**${x}**`) `` means that after a match is found, the match is passed to an arrow function where `x` is the whole match and `y` is the Group 1 value. If Group 1 value matches, its value is used to replace the match, else, the whole match is wrapped with double asterisks.

Alternatively, you may use a known workaround with a negative lookahead that will work only in case you have a paired amount of backticks in the string:

```js
\bupgrade\b(?=(?:[^`]*`[^`]*`)*[^`]*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j8USe2/2/).

The `` (?=(?:[^`]*`[^`]*`)*[^`]*$) `` lookahead matches a location that is immediately followed with

- `` (?:[^`]*`[^`]*`)* `` zero or more repetitions of any zero or more chars other than a backtick, followed with a backtick, then again any zero or more chars other than a backtick and again a backtick
- `` [^`]* `` - any zero or more chars other than a backtick
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thaks Wiktor for the quick and informative answer. I have just added those asterisks to explain the readers about what words should be selected. Actually, I need to wrap `x` with jsx element. But string.replace will not return a jsx element.

Comment: @Vishal What do you mean by "jsx element"? Just replace `**`s with what you need. Regex only works on strings anyway.

Comment: JSX element is a react element. But don't worry about that. What I meant to say is I don't want to use string.replace. Instead, I want to split the string by x. But the way your regex works, I can not split it without replace.

Comment: @Vishal Does [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/j8USe2/2) work for you?

Comment: Yeah! that one work perfectly. Thanks for that. Can you please add it to the answer?

Comment: @Vishal Yes, have just added it.